# warning: a: circular name reference in Merge Sort using recursive functions in bash

Tags: bash, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort in bash based on same in C, here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function merge() {
    local -n a=$1
    local low=$2
    local mid=$3
    local high=$4
    for ((l1 = low, l2 = mid + 1, i = low; l1 <= mid && l2 <= high; i++)); do
        if [[ a[$l1] -le a[$l2] ]]; then
            b[$i]=${a[((l1++))]}
        else
            b[$i]=${a[((l2++))]}
        fi
    done
    while [[ $l1 -le $mid ]]; do
        b[((i++))]=${a[((l2++))]}
    done
    while [[ $l2 -le $high ]]; do
        b[((i++))]=${a[((l2++))]}
    done
    for ((i = low; i <= high; i++)); do
        a[$i]=${b[$i]}
    done
}

function sort() {
    local -n a=$1
    local low=$2
    local high=$3
    echo "a=${a[*]}"
    echo "low=$low"
    echo "high=$high"

    if [[ $low < $high ]]; then
        mid=$(((low + high) / 2))
        sort a "$low" $mid
        sort a $((mid + 1)) "$high"
        merge a "$low" $mid "$high"
    else
        echo "${arr[@]}"
    fi
}

declare -a arr
echo "Enter the elements of the array: "
read -ra arr
len=${#arr[@]}
echo $len
sort arr 0 $((len - 1))

echo "Array after sort;"
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

After execution, I get same error spam saying:

> warning: a: circular name reference

Full log: https://del.dog/error-log.txt

What I interpret is, recursive functions and namerefs don't go hand in hand in bash. Is there some way I can achieve merge sort in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namerefs reference variables by their *name*. Therefore, these references are not like pointers in C. Instead, namerefs might reference a different variable then intended if the scope changes.

Here is your problem boiled down to its core.

```
countdown() {
  local -n a="$1"
  if (( a > 0 )); then
    echo "$(( a-- ))"
    countdown a
  fi
}
b=3
countdown b
```

If you execute `countdown` you end up with `local -n a=a` after the first level of recursion. To circumvent this problem simply recurse using the name of the global variable referenced by `a` (`${!a}` = `b`) rather than `a` itself:

```
countdown() {
  local -n a="$1"
  if (( a > 0 )); then
    echo "$(( a-- ))"
    countdown "${!a}"
  fi
}
b=3
countdown b
```

**tl;dr:** Call `sort/merge "${!a}"` instead of `sort/merge a`.

**By the way:** The index of bash arrays is always an arithmetic expression. You can write `a[i]=...` and `... "${a[i++]}"`. No need for `$(( ... )))` here.

Also, I think you wanted to write `if (( low < high ))` instead of `if [[ $low < $high` because ...

> When used with [[, the ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators sort lexicographically using the current locale

... meaning `29 < 3`.

Comment: I need to call sort() inside sort(), how can I perform that without circular name references?

Comment: If I call sort inside sort via
> sort a
That'll again create `local -n a=a` right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I totally overlooked that second circular reference. Apologies for the wrong information. I fixed the answer and hope that it solves the problem now.